# relocation against xxx in read-only section '.text' - wrong compiler or linux setup in SUSE?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, suse, dynamic-library

I'm not a frequent user of Linux and I think I did something wrong.

This is the code for a test dynamic library ".so" I'm generating.

```
class InternalClass
{
public:
    int Function(){ return 10; }
};

extern "C"
{
    int WrapperFunctionSimple() { return 10; }
    void WrapperCreateInstance() {InternalClass* item = new InternalClass(); delete item; }
}
```

The compilation fails with the following error:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -O2  -c /home/lidia/compartida/TestLibrary/TestLibrary/main.cpp -o obj/Release/main.o
g++ -shared  obj/Release/main.o  -o bin/Release/libTestLibrary.so -s  
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: obj/Release/main.o: warning: relocation against `_Znwm@@GLIBCXX_3.4' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: obj/Release/main.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Znwm@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried with -fPIC as suggested and it compiles. But when using this library, It cannot be loaded when I add that last function:

```
void WrapperCreateInstance() {InternalClass* item = new InternalClass(); delete item; }
```

The problem is using the InternalClass, without this function everything works.

---

I'm using VirtualBox. I installed OpenSUSE 64bit, the app that uses the library is also 64bit. In another linux distribution (Mint), with exactly the same project and settings (without fPIC), it can be compiled. When I use that library (.so) it works in SUSE.

I'm also using :

- gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
- g++ (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
- My IDE is Code::Blocks 20 (last version). Settings are empty except for the -m64 flag.

---

What am I doing wrong? This seems like something advanced Linux users could help me understand.

EDIT:
To add more information, this can compile in Ubuntu with the same settings. Not in SUSE

Comment: What does "It cannot be loaded" mean?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It means that I get a DllImportException ( I use it from c# ), but it says the library cannot be loaded in the debug log. No more information returned

Comment: I've tried reproducing the loading issue (used `-fPIC`) but a simple `dlopen` on the resulting shared library works. Please post what error you get from `dlerror()`, maybe try loading it from a C program first instead of C#

Answer (score 13):

It happened to me when I used GCC to compile a CPP file. So for C++ files use g++ only, and obviously not GCC, which is meant for c files.

Comment: gcc means GNU compiler collection, and g++ is c++ gcc compiler

Comment: Thanks. That was my issue too. Unfortunately for you, the author already uses `g++` so I can't upvote you.

Answer (score 11):

To me it happened, if one library (A) depends on another one (B) and library A was linked before library B. The solution is to link library B first and then A.

Comment: Can you also explain how can library A be linked before library B when using something like g++ or gcc?

Answer (score 6):

In my case this happened when I had an abstract class A and two derived classes B and C like below.

```
class BaseAbstractClass
{
public:
    virtual void doNothing(void) = 0;
};

class A : public BaseAbstractClass
{
public:
    void doNothing(void){
        return;
    }
};

class B : public BaseAbstractClass
{
public:
    void doNothing(void);    // Only declaration, definition is nowhere
};
```

But one of derived classes (`class B` here) has only declaration of `doNothing()`, but lacks definition anywhere in project files.

Comment: I had the same issue with only two classes, Base and Derived, but my ~Derived() was only declared and not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I am using cmake and GCC in ubuntu and I got the same error.

In my case, I added the XX.h file to include directories, and used in my main.cpp a "typedef struct x" which is defined in XX.h header file. However I forgot to add XX.c to the executable sources.

This error is cleared when I added XX.c to the target executable sources in add_executable() of Cmake.

I hope I can clearly state my case.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error on my project, **both error messages**.

I use CMake. In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I had such a code:

```
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC  ${HEADERS}
    PRIVATE ${SOURCES}
    )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
   AnotherLib
)
```

A `.cpp` (mentioned in the SOURCES) was the culprit, it was not accessed. **Removing `PRIVATE` fixed the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the order of linking answer was useful for me. It ended up being I was including the cpp file rather than the header (include was called at wrong time.)

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that .h and .c files were not linked properly by the gcc compiler (using plain C).
the fix was to run the compilation command with all including c-files. so it was

`gcc main_program.c sub_prog1.c sub_prog2.c sub_prog3.c`

another fix is to post `#include "sub_progX.c"` at the end of each sub_progX.h-file.

Might come back to post a better solution, but it's what I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar linker failures when the linker -o mybin  was missing.
You could check when you compile with:

```
make --warn-undefined-variables
```

I saw you are using CMake, so you'll need to adapt your approach.

Essentially one .o file is probably missing, or some mistake between using CC and CXX in your build.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the library(libinihcpp.a) which is problem have to be linked separately by INTERFACE not PRIVATE in CMakeLists.txt

from

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Python3_LIBRARIES} libinihcpp.a)
```

to

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Python3_LIBRARIES)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE  libinihcpp.a)
```