# Linking issues "relocation against `g_GIT_SHA1' in read-only section `.text'" and "undefined reference to `g_GIT_SHA1'"

Tags: c++, cmake

I was trying to follow the procedure in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4318642 with a test:

CMakeFile.txt

```
#cmake version setup
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(Checksumtest VERSION 1.0
        LANGUAGES  CXX
    )

if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
endif()

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
include(GetGitRevisionDescription)
get_git_head_revision(GIT_REFSPEC GIT_SHA1)

configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp" @ONLY)
set(LIB_LIST "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/checksum/GitSHA1.h")
add_library(checksum SHARED ${LIB_LIST})
target_include_directories(checksum PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/checksum")
#target_compile_features(checksum PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
target_compile_options(checksum PRIVATE -O3 -fPIC)

add_executable(test_checksum test.cpp)
target_compile_features(test_checksum PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
target_compile_options(test_checksum PRIVATE -O3)
target_link_libraries(test_checksum PRIVATE checksum)
target_include_directories(test_checksum PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/checksum")
```

GitSHA1.h

```
extern const char g_GIT_SHA1[];
```

GitSHA1.cpp.in

```
#define GIT_SHA1 "@GIT_SHA1@"
const char g_GIT_SHA1[] = GIT_SHA1;
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GitSHA1.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    std::cout<<"Checksum"<<" "<<g_GIT_SHA1<<std::endl;
}
```

I tried several options but I always get an error like this:

```
FAILED: checksum/test_checksum 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -g -rdynamic checksum/CMakeFiles/test_checksum.dir/test.cpp.o -o checksum/test_checksum  -Wl,-rpath,/home/francesco/Simula/b-EdgeCover/cmake-build-debug/checksum  checksum/libchecksum.so && :
/usr/bin/ld: checksum/CMakeFiles/test_checksum.dir/test.cpp.o: warning: relocation against `g_GIT_SHA1' in read-only section `.text.startup'
/usr/bin/ld: checksum/CMakeFiles/test_checksum.dir/test.cpp.o: in function `std::char_traits<char>::length(char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/char_traits.h:371: undefined reference to `g_GIT_SHA1'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

What can I do?

Edit 1: I tried with the fixes findable with some researches (i.e. [relocation against xxx in read-only section '.text' - wrong compiler or linux setup in SUSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65407610/18568336)), but I cannot solve it in any way. Anyone did have a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

Add to GitSHA1.cpp:

```
#include GitSHA1.h
```

For the rationale check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894897/7268445